# How can I select more than one folder on Onedrive client so I can synchronize them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, onedrive, cloud-storage

So usually, when you login the OneDrive client on Windows 10, you get a folder that is named `OneDrive`. When you create a file in here it is uploaded to the OneDrive, this part is clear right?

But what about that case, when you have a different folder, which is named `projects` and you don't want to duplicate the folder and copy to `OneDrive`, but you want to upload it to the cloud?

Is it possible to synchronize both folders at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this kind of problem is to make use of 'junctions' or 'symbolic links'. In short a junction or a symbolic link is a comfortable way to reach a certain directory on a Windows filesystem folder from other places (e.g. from another directory on the same or from another volume). The difference between junctions and symbolic links in short is that junctions can not point to network drives but only to local attached volumes. However, a symbolic link has the ability to point a network target with a UNC file name.

For me a junction is normally sufficient so my answer refers only to junctions. But the same can be reached with symbolic links.

To clarify the concept here is an example using two different junctions:

- original (target) folder: C:\tmp\my_project
- created junction no. 1: C:\tmp2\junction_2_my_project
- created junction no. 2: D:\another_junction_2_my_project

In this example 2 junctions exist which point to the same (target) folder on C:. The content of the target folder can now be reached and modified on three different ways.

Note: Each one of the two junctions can be deleted at any time without destroying the target folder. The junction is just some sort of 'link' or 'abbreviation' to reach target folder in the filesystem hierarchy.

This method can be used for cloud services like OneDrive or Dropbox which allow only one root folder to synchronize. If I need to synchronize a second (target) folder which is not located under the root folder of the cloud service I have to create a junction to this folder and place this junction inside the root folder of the cloud service. If my target folder resides on a network drive I have to create and use a symbolic link instead of a junction.

Regarding the example above:

- created junction no. 3: E:\OneDrive\finally_junction_2_my_project

Of course I can name the junction only like that: E:\OneDrive\my_project. It's up to you not to forget that this is just a junction and not the original project folder. From now on you can modify your folder contents inside the OneDrive or Dropbox folder, and the contents will be synchronized as usual. If you don't need the junction or symbolic link inside the cloud service anymore, you just have to delete the junction or symbolic link. The content of the original (target) folder will then not be deleted.

There are different ways and third party tools to create junctions or symbolic links inside the Windows. In the command shell (cmd) [mklink.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx) can be used:

- create a junction: mklink /j "E:\OneDrive\junction_2_project" "c:\tmp\my_project"
- create a symbolic: mklink "E:\OneDrive\symlink_2_project" "c:\tmp\my_project"

If mklink.exe is not available in your Window Edition it's possible to create junctions with '[junction.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction)' from Sysinternals.

Personally I prefer to create junctions (or symbolic links) inside my filemanager ([Xyplorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/)) or with the Windows shell extension '[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)' which was already mentioned in the other answer because it's more comfortable than to use the Windows command shell.

Note: Creating a symbolic link requires higher privileges than creating a junction. Therefore I prefer to use junctions.

Answer (score -1):

I found something in this article http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

With this program you can create a symbolic link to the folder.

But what does that mean?

Let's say you have a folder, which is named is `a` and you want to link content with folder `b` without storing the files. With this program, you can do it one or two clicks, really simple.

Just download the and install the Link Shell Extension program linked to above.

After that, follow the example. That is:

1. Right click folder `a`
2. Select the `Pick link source` option
3. Right click folder `b`
4. Select the `Drop as` drop-down menu.
5. Select the `symbolic link` option.
   That's it you're done, the folder is now linked.

Comment: Link-only answers are not that helpful to the community.

Comment: But the link contain all nessecery information including the progam.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: Well without the relevant information this answer is not helpful to me, any answer with just a link, is not helpful.  So just fix it, please, read the help center.

Comment: Better now?
I think it is..