# Need to transfer a large folder to OneDrive -- what are my options?

Tags: file-transfer, onedrive

I have a folder on a local disk that has about 1TB of data that I need to transfer to a OneDrive folder. Synching it up through a OneDrive folder on the same computer does not seem to be a practical option, since it seems I need the same amount of free space to hold a temporary copy of the data before it gets uploaded to the cloud, and I don't have that much space.

If I simply drag the root folder to the browser directly, I am assuming this transfer won't require extra local space, but if there is any sort of hiccup during this transfer -- such as the internet connection going down -- the transfer will break and I would have to start from scratch.

What are my alternatives? Is there a tool that would allow me to migrate that much data without having to babysit the process, or transfer manually in a million chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly add an extra folder to OneDrive to Backup. Only the OneDrive base folder and the pre-defined locations Documents, Pictures and Desktop folders.
So just the mklink command to make a shortcut in one of these folders that points towards to real folder were you have this large data-set.

Please note: if you want to sync this back on another PC (or the same PC after a re-install) the linked folder will become a real folder. So stop that sync as soon as the folder is created. Move it to the proper location and re-create the link. Then let OneDrive continue restoring it.

I used this method myself in the past when my computer had a small and very full SSD as C: and I had a large classic HDD as D: drive.

See also [How can I select more than one folder on Onedrive client so I can synchronize them?](https://superuser.com/questions/1076033/how-can-i-select-more-than-one-folder-on-onedrive-client-so-i-can-synchronize-th?rq=1)

EDIT: After poster clarified that he can't access OneDrive directly from the computer holding the files (I presume a Linux machine) a different approach is needed.

I never tried this myself, but it ought to work.

OneDrive is essentially a personal Sharepoint site to which the files are upload and which you can access via a web-browser.
That also means that you can access the web-site as a so-called web-dav share.
So mount the web-dav share as if it where a drive.
And then just rsync your files to that drive. rsync will happily resume after it has been aborted so you can easily resume the upload whenever needed.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand correctly. I have a folder `c:\Users\<my user folder>\OneDrive` that is synchronized with my OneDrive cloud storage. The data is located on a network attached device with the root folder being something like `\\foobar\blah\rootdir`. So do I need to mklink rootdir to a folder inside my local OneDrive folder?

Comment: @IZ You never mentioned the data is to be accessed via a network share/other computer. That invalidates my answer. I presumed you had it on a local disk of a computer that can access OneDrive and just wanted to avoid copying it to another folder. Making a link to a network location is technically possible but that will cause all sorts of other problems. I won't go there.

Comment: @IZ Expanded my answer with another approach.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try. I am on a Win10 machine though

Comment: @IZ OS doesn’t matter. Approach is the same.